# Hotel refund with hotels.com

Tags: hotels, cancellations, refunds

In February this year I had a hotel booked with hotels.com. It was classed as non refundable but was cancelled because the hotel went into administration just before travelling. Hotels.com promised a refund. It did not send refund so I telephoned again to be told refund had been processed. I checked with my bank and it had not. I have been very patient due to coronavirus but I cant get through by phone, chatline is not helpful and they do not provide an email.

Comment: How did you pay? Have you tried asking your bank to initiate a chargeback request?